# How to create registry entry based on windows type?

Tags: registry, inno-setup

i would like that my installation will install registry entry bellow in  64-bit OS . And if OS is 32-bit, it will be without **"Wow6432Node**" Because for 32-bit Wow6432Node does not exsit.

Second question will this: `Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty` delete installed registry?

Thank you for help.

```
; File created by Converter v.0.1.4 -        10 září 2013ă.,   18 6r.  02 2in. 26 26ec.
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: DisplayName; ValueData: Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows™ - Part 1; Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: CD Drive; ValueData: E:\; Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: ProductName; ValueData: Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows™ - Part 1; Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: Folder; ValueData: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows(TM) - Part 1\; Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: Install Dir; ValueData: C:\Program Files (x86)\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows(TM) - Part 1\; Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: Installed From; ValueData: E:\; Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: Locale; ValueData: en_UK; Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: Language; ValueData: English (UK); Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: Product GUID; ValueData: {{C9AAF970-4E7E-4C98-AD67-09C74379D345}; Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: Suppression Exe; Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: Registration; ValueData: Software\Electronic Arts\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1\ergc; Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1\1.0; ValueType: string; ValueName: DisplayName; ValueData: Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1\1.0; ValueType: dword; ValueName: Language; ValueData: $00000013; Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1\1.0; ValueType: string; ValueName: LanguageName; ValueData: English (UK); Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1\1.0; ValueType: string; ValueName: ProgramGroup; ValueData: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Electronic Arts\; Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty
; time elapsed:      4 msec.
```

Comment: Don't specify the `Wow` path. That's just a registry reflection for 32-bit applications on a 64-bit system. Just keep the `Root` key as it is (without bitness suffix) and use only `SubKey: "Software\Electronic Arts\..."`. In that case the Inno Setup will *"store those values to the 32-bit view"* of the registry on 64-bit systems.

Comment: OK. But my 64-bit system i have this in Wow6432Node i am not sure if i change this to Software\Electronic Arts\.... and i will install game that it will works. Every 32 bit aplication  that i have is in Wow6432Node.

Comment: If you use standard `HKLM` and the setup is `32bit`, then all registry entries will go into normal `HKLM` in 32bit systems and in `Wow6432Node` in 64bit systems. Your code should be: `Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1\1.0...`. You do not and you should not point manually to `Wow6432Node` branch.

Answer (score 2):

**Ist Question:** If u want to install registry(your application) in both 64/32 bit then just remove the **`Wow6432Node`** part.Without any doubt.The **`Wow6432Node`** part will be created in 64 bit automatically. *Is that so simple?* Yes!

**2nd Question :** I don't know will `Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty` delete registry or not but it better to use `Flags: uninsdeletekey` for single 
registry. With `Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty` you can remove the `Electronic Arts` parts which will not remove with `Flags: uninsdeletekey` but you can remove by this way.

Please look at the sample registry script:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts; Flags: dontcreatekey uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty dontcreatekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: DisplayName; ValueData: Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows™ - Part 1; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: CD Drive; ValueData: E:\; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: ProductName; ValueData: Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows™ - Part 1; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: Folder; ValueData: {group}; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: Install Dir; ValueData: {app}; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: Installed From; ValueData: {src}; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: Locale; ValueData: en_UK; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: Language; ValueData: English (UK); Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: Product GUID; ValueData: {{C9AAF970-4E7E-4C98-AD67-09C74379D345}; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: Suppression Exe; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; ValueType: string; ValueName: Registration; ValueData: Software\Electronic Arts\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1\ergc; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1\1.0; ValueType: string; ValueName: DisplayName; ValueData: Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1\1.0; ValueType: dword; ValueName: Language; ValueData: $00000013; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1\1.0; ValueType: string; ValueName: LanguageName; ValueData: English (UK); Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1\1.0; ValueType: string; ValueName: ProgramGroup; ValueData: {group}; Flags: uninsdeletekey
```